# Как убрать повторы в случайных числах?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть генератор случайных чисел от 0 до 3 при клике. Как исключить повторы, чтоб следующее число не совпадало с предыдущим?

Comment: Не совпало только с *предыдущим*, или надо каждое число от 0 до 3 получить лишь по одному разу, в случайном порядке?

Comment: (понаписал комментариев, а забыл уточнить) Чтоб не совпадало только с одним предыдущим или вообще со всеми предыдущими?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Запоминайте предыдущее выпавшее число.

Если это первый раз, *предыдущее* ещё не определено – вариантов 4 (0,1,2,3) – просто берёте случайное от 0 до 3.

Если *предыдущее* определено, то случайных вариантов осталось на 1 меньше – всего 3. Получайте случайное значение от 0 до 2 и прибавляйте к нему 1, когда выпало большее или равное *предыдущему*.

```
пред.  варианты  диапазон  rand  >=пред.  корр  результат
-      0 1 2 3   0 1 2 3   2     –        +0    2
2      0 1 _ 3   0 1 2     2     да       +1    3
3      0 1 2 _   0 1 2     1     нет      +0    1
1      0 _ 2 3   0 1 2     2     да       +1    3
```

**Рабочий код:**

```js
var out = document.getElementById("out"), previous, total=4;
function getRandom(){
  var n = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( isNaN( previous) ? total : total - 1));
  if( !isNaN( previous)  &&  n >= previous) n++;
  out.innerHTML = previous = n;
}
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", getRandom);
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Заполните массив последовательными номерами, затем перемешайте случайным образом — получите гарантированно неповторяющуюся последовательность и при этом избежите проверок на коллизии.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35305431/272885
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/272885

Comment: у этого способа есть один маленький недостаток. Если нужно не более 4 чисел, то все ок. А вот если больше - то человеку нужно будет повторно генерировать следующую четверку чисел. И вот так может оказаться, что последнее число в первом наборе совпадет с первым числом в следующим. И вероятность такого события для 4 чисел достаточно высока - 25%.

Comment: Не понимаю откуда вы взяли число 4 :) Сколько надо, столько и сделаем.

Comment: в условии сказано - числа от 0 до 3.

Comment: Ok. Топикстартер говорил про 4 числа, но алгоритм ими не ограничен.  В чём вы видите "маленький недостаток способа"? Если вам понадобится 10 чисел — делайте массив длиной 10. Алгоритм тот же.

Comment: топикстартер скорее всего имеет ввиду последовательности вида 012302310132...

Comment: 1) Мы не знаем что имел в виду автор вопроса. 2) Перемешанный массив уникальных значений гарантирует, что даже "ходя по кругу" мы *не повторим предыдущее число*.

Comment: @artoodetoo один раз перемешали, последней получилась тройка. Снова перемешали случайно (не будете же по кругу гонять), первой выпала тройка – две тройки подряд.

Comment: @Sergiks SO это не форум с бесконечным развитием темы, это Q-and-A. Вы можете сформулировать свой вопрос с новыми деталями. Суть вашего уточнения я понимаю, но автор вопроса такиих деталей не давал, а своё одобрение ответа уже выразил.

Answer (score 4):

Записывайте те числа которые уже генератор выдал, а потом в следующий раз проверяйте было такое число или нет.

Comment: Только надо не забыть учесть, что от 0 до 3 не так много чисел (если речь идет о целых). Просто сомнительно, чтобы эта проблема была актуальна для чисел с плавающей точкой.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно это будет глупо, но я использовал условия (if, else) и пустую переменную в которую записывал случайное значение. Пример на слайдере в коде ниже. В таком случае случайные числа никогда не будут повторяться.

```
  setInterval(() => {
    //projects.length = 3, step = 0
    let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * projects.length);

    if (step == index) {
      switch (index) {
        case 0:
          index = 1; step = 1; break;
        default:
          index = 0; step = 0; break;
      }
    } else {
      step = index;
    }
    createProject(index);
  }, 4000);
```

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст ответа можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа.

Comment: Спасибо, изменил, если правильно понял :)